# fscanf - segmentation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

Was trying to write a little program when faced a problem that has never occured to me before. There seems to be a segmentation fault in fscanf function, though can't really figure the problem out. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fin = ("file.in", "r");
    int n, t;
    fscanf(fin, "%d %d", &n, &t);
    return 0;
}
```

And the file.in:

```
3 19
```

Hope you have some ideas. Any help appreciated!
Rugile :)

Comment: Why, **oh why** are you not compiling with warnings enabled? ***Why?***

Comment: @H2CO3 compiling with warnings is default in GCC :-)

Comment: @KVD But not enough of them. `-Wall` at least, better `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. But anyways, you can always `s/compiling with/pay attention to/` to get a different interpretation. (which is equally sad, isn't it?)

Comment: @H2CO3 -Wall is not required if popping up warnings. I use GCC in Command Line every time :)

Comment: @KVD So do I. And it doesn't display all warnings without `-Wall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninitialized variables `FILE *fin = ("file.in", "r");` - cause Undefined behaviors.

```
FILE *fin = fopen ("file.in", "r");
```

It compiles because `("file.in", "r")` evaluates to `"r"` due to Comma operator effect.

Comment: But it shouldn't compile even then. `"r"` has type `char [2]`, decaying into `char *`, whereas `fin` is of type `FILE *`...

Comment: @H2CO3 - Depends how the compiler (version etc) treats it - it compiles http://ideone.com/QyNvrv and i see no reason why it should not because in both cases we get a memory reference. The problem is with the type. The compiler should at least generate a warning though.

Comment: @Acme 1. What "reference"? C has no references. And no, it shan't compile, since pointers to incompatible types are being assigned to each other.

Comment: @H2CO3 - `"reference"` i meant address - i misquoted.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *fin = fopen ("file.in", "r");
```

If doing like `FILE *fin = ("file.in", "r");`

GCC Reports:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Why it can be compiled without `fopen`?

Comment: @johny No syntax errors, but logical errors, and function usage errors

Comment: @johny It should give an 'incompatible pointer' warning: without `fopen` the r-value of the expression is seen as a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) of which the result will be the right-most expression, in this case `"r"`. This *is* a valid pointer, but not one that points to a `FILE`. Thus a warning for incompatible pointers.